# Как отменить фильтр или акцию плагина, например, запуск скрипта?

Tags: wordpress

Часто возникает ситуация, когда надо отменить (не запускать) скрипт, подключаемый плагином. Править код плагина плохо, потому что правки слетят при обновлении.

Хотелось бы знать, как отменить какие-либо фильтры или акции, устанавливаемые плагином по `add_filter()` или `add_action()`, учитывая, что многие современные плагины используют объектно-ориентированный код.

Как в общем случае внести такие изменения, не затрагивая код плагина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Функциональный стиль**

Если плагин написан в функциональном стиле, то это довольно просто. Смотрим, как плагин запускает скрипт или добавляет фильтр. Например:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uni_avatar_scripts');
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'uni_wp_title', 20, 2 );
```

и отменяем их в functions.php

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uni_avatar_scripts');
remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'uni_wp_title', 20 );
```

Обратите внимание на третий аргумент - приоритет. Он должен точно соответствовать приоритету, указанному при добавлении хука.

**Объектно-ориентированный стиль**

Проблема, однако, в том, что большинство современных плагинов используют объектно-ориентированный код, и воторой аргумент при добавленни хука - уже массив с указанием объекта и его функции:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueuePublicScriptsAndStyles' ));    
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', array( $this, 'wp_get_nav_menu_items_filter' ), 10, 2 );
```

Как добраться до этого `$this`?

Решением может служить следующая функция, добавленная в `functions.php` темы:

```
/**
 * Remove current action or filter from plugin.
 *
 * @param string $class_name Class name enqueueing the action.
 * @param null $action_name
 */
function remove_plugin_action( $class_name, $action_name = null ) {
    global $wp_filter;

    if ( null === $action_name ) {
        $action_name = current_action();
    }

    /** @var $hooks WP_Hook */
    $hooks = $wp_filter[ $action_name ];

    $callbacks = $hooks->callbacks;

    foreach ( $callbacks as $priority => $actions ) {
        foreach ( $actions as $action ) {
            $function = $action['function'];
            if ( is_array( $function ) && ( $class_name === get_class( $function[0] ) ) ) {
                remove_action( $action_name , $function, $priority );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Поскольку акции и фильтры по сути одно и то же, и хранятся в одном глобальном массиве `$wp_filter`, код универсален.

Использование для удаления акции:

```
function remove_scripts_action() {
    // Удаляем акцию wp_enqueue_scripts (текущую), запущенную из объекта с классом PublicEngine
    // Класс смотрим в исходном коде плагина
    remove_plugin_action( 'PublicEngine' );
}
// Задаём приоритет 0, чтобы наша акция отмены выполнилась раньше запуска скрипта.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_scripts_action', 0 );
```

Использование для удаления фильтра:

```
function remove_nav_filter( $items ) {
    remove_plugin_action( 'WPML_LS_Render' );

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'remove_nav_filter', 0, 2 );
```