# Как сделать загрузку js файла с дочерней темы?

Tags: wordpress

```html
  function child_script() {
  wp_dequeue_script( 'ct-fullwidth-optimizer' );
  wp_enqueue_script('ct-fullwidth-optimizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ct-fullwidth-loader.js', false, false, false);
   wp_dequeue_script( 'ct-scripts' );
     wp_enqueue_script('ct-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array('jquery', 'ct-form-elements', 'odometr', 'ct-sticky', 'jquery-dlmenu'), false, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_script', 9999);
```

У родителя есть файл app.js могу я в дочерней теме создать свой файл app.js что бы он перебивал предыдущий? то есть он даже не будет загружаться а будут с дочерней темы браться?
Добавил первый вариант кода ничего не изменилось. Потом попробывал 2 вариант кода и скрипты просто перестали работать. Они не подключатся с дочерней темы

```html
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );

function de_script() {
 wp_dequeue_script( 'ct-fullwidth-optimizer' );
 wp_deregister_script( 'ct-fullwidth-optimizer' );

   wp_dequeue_script( '  ct-scripts' );
 wp_deregister_script( '  ct-scripts' );
}
```

Comment: Надо отменить запуск скрипта из родительской темы. Здесь я писал, как это сделать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822164/Как-отменить-фильтр-или-акцию-плагина-например-запуск-скрипта. А потом запустить свой скрипт в дочерней теме.

Comment: Смотрите там примерно такое
function name {
wp_enqueue_script(1 ..... );
wp_enqueue_script(2 .......);
wp_enqueue_script(3 .... );
.....
wp_enqueue_script(10 ...);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'name');
если добавлю фильтр отлючатся все скрипты же можно выделить 1?

Comment: Выложили бы сразу код запуска скрипта, который надо отменить, прямо в вопросе - мы бы избавились от лишней переписки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда много скриптов запускается одной функцией, отменять акцию нельзя - отменятся все. Надо так:

В дочерней теме в functions.php пишете

```
function add_child_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'script_1' );
    wp_enqueue_script('script_1', $script_url, array(...) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_child_scripts', 9999 );
```

add_child_scripts должна запускаться позднее, чем аналог в родительской теме (см. 9999 ). dependency ( array(...) ) должны быть такие же, как в родительской теме.

Comment: что-то не выходит. Добавил код как делал

Comment: где файл app.js в вопросе? Приведите его в порядок. Выкладывать вариант моего ответа туда не надо.